# Javascript: Save uploaded file

Tags: javascript

I would like to save uploaded file using javascript, in my linux server. The code I wrote is:

```
if (uploadInput.files.length == 0) {
            console.log("No file is uploaded. ");
    } else {
            console.log("File uploaded.");
            var file = uploadInput.files[0];                
            }
```

Now I would like to save that file as "files/upload.csv". Can anyone please advise, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Save where? in the downloads folder?

Comment: Saving uploaded files are handled on the server, not on the client - this looks like client-side code.

Comment: Anywhere in the local server!!

Comment: `in my linux server` - so that code is server code or client code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm going to do is walk you through the logic, instead of providing code. There is just not enough information here on what you want to do to provide actual code and the sample you provided is a very small part of what the actual solution would need to include.

I'm assuming the code you wrote above is meant to run on a website visitor's browser (client-side). **Client-side code can't save to a server.** What it can do, is send the *file contents* to the server. But then you'd need something on the server side to process that file contents and actually save it to the server-side files directory.

One method to send the file contents from the client to the server is to use AJAX - you can do this with native javascript, but I would recommend looking into a library such as Jquery, which makes it a lot easier. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ This AJAX code will need a communication point on the server to send the file contents to. From your profile it seems you're familiar with PHP. You could make a php file on the server (say receivefilecontents.php) that takes in input from that client-side AJAX call, and then saves it to a server directory - you could also do this in Python, Java or a number of other languages.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the logic mate. I was able to work through it. :)